# how split and parsing data in Java

Tags: java, parsing, split

Please help,
how to change data received from the serial data into data tables, I have problems splitting data.

data from the serial:

```
    &&
    1301830000
    13020
    130 313
    130432803
    1305160420
    1306155033
    130 735
    1308746.119995
    1309738.062073
    !!
    &&
    1401830000
    14020
    140 314
    140432803
    1405160420
    1406155033
    140 735
    1408746.119995
    !!
```

data is preceded by a "&&" and end with "!!". and data between the marks to be converted into data tables. The first two digits are the index data reception, I want to start to change next digit, eg:

```
   &&
   1301830000
   13020
   !!
```

```
13 index data. 01  rows and columns. 830000 value
13 index data. 02  rows and columns. 0      value
```

making it

```
      col0    col1
row0  830000  0
```

thanks

Comment: is your data corrupted or is it really '130 313', not '130313' in line 4 of the data? same in 3 other lines

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if the problem was how to parse the lines between the start/stop markers, or if the problem is parsing the individual lines, but the below code should get you started.

I didn't bother with any string -> number conversion.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    String input = "    &&\n" + 
            "    1301830000\n" + 
            "    13020\n" + 
            "    130 313\n" + 
            "    130432803\n" + 
            "    1305160420\n" + 
            "    1306155033\n" + 
            "    130 735\n" + 
            "    1308746.119995\n" + 
            "    1309738.062073\n" + 
            "    !!\n" + 
            "    &&\n" + 
            "    1401830000\n" + 
            "    14020\n" + 
            "    140 314\n" + 
            "    140432803\n" + 
            "    1405160420\n" + 
            "    1406155033\n" + 
            "    140 735\n" + 
            "    1408746.119995\n" + 
            "    !!\n";

    try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input))) {
        String line;
        while((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            if (line.startsWith("&&") || line.startsWith("!!")) {
                continue;
            } else {
                String indexData = line.substring(0, 2);
                String rowsColumns = line.substring(2, 4);
                String value = line.substring(4); 
                System.out.println(String.format("%2s index data. %3s rows and columns. %6s value ", indexData, rowsColumns, value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```